# Dropdown selection not changing to current value with Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I' m getting items from Firestore and displaying them in a dropdown. When i select an item from the dropdown list, I get the selection printed in console but the selected item doesn't change.
Im using a map selectedValue["add"] to add a total item price and selectedValue["nom"] to get the selected item name.

```
List<int> dropdownValues = [];
Map opMap;
List<DropdownMenuItem> items = [];
  final itemExtras = snap.data.documents[i]['op'];
       for (var extra in itemExtras) {
        if (extra['add'] > 0) {
         items.add(
          DropdownMenuItem(
           child: Text(
             extra['nom'] +' + Bs. ' + extra['add'].toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight:
              FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              value: extra, //this is a map value
              ),
                );
                  } else {
                     items.add(
                      DropdownMenuItem(
                       child: Text(
                       extra['nom'],
                       style: TextStyle(
                       fontWeight:
                       FontWeight.bold),),
                       value: extra,
                        ),
                      );
                     }
                    }
```

and this is my menu button

```
DropdownButton(
 isExpanded: true,
 items: items,
 value: opMap, // i think the issue may be here
 style: Theme.of(context)
        .textTheme
        .title,
 onChanged: (selectedValue) {
            setState(() {
            opMap = selectedValue;
            dropdownValues[i] = selectedValue["add"]; 
            addPrice =dropdownValues.fold(
                     0,
                      (previous, current) =>
                       previous + current);
                       total = (addPrice +=
                       widget.snapshot[
                       'price']);});
                        print(opMap);
                                    },
        hint: Text('Select'),
```

))

Answer (score 0):

I think, you could change the value, since it is a whole index by default, you could try with this:

```
int valueTemp;

DropdownButton(
 isExpanded: true,
 value: valueTemp,
 item: item.map((val)=>DropdownMenuItem(
                         value: val.id,
                          child: Text(
                           val.description,
                            style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                             fontSize: 16.0
                          ),
                       )
                    )).toList(),
 style: Theme.of(context)
        .textTheme
        .title,
 onChanged: (selectedValue) {
            setState(() {
            valueTemp = selectedValue;
            })
```

Comment: Still stuck, im using more than two values generated by mi firestore snapshot length in each drop downbutton thats way i need to return a map value .